# OpenTK GL.VertexAttribPointer() call producing INVALID_OPERATION error

Tags: opengl, opentk

I'm calling GL.VertexAttribPointer on my first vertex attribute, and the call is producing an INVALID_OPERATION error.  I don't know what that means, as the OpenGL API doesn't list that as one of the errors a VertexAttribPointer call can make: (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml).

Here's the code immediately around where the error is being set:

```
GL.BindVertexArray(mi_VAOHandle);

OpenGLUtilityLib.CheckError("binding vertex array");

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Binding attribute...");
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
OpenGLUtilityLib.CheckError("Enabling VAA 0");
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, mi_PositionBufferHandle);
OpenGLUtilityLib.CheckError("Binding position buffer to array buffer target");
GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);
OpenGLUtilityLib.CheckError("Set vertex attribute pointer");
```

That last error check returns an error.

For context, I've been refactoring some beginner OpenTK GL code into an object oriented structure when I got this error, and my procedural copy still works, and I'm doing everything in the same order, so I'm wondering if something might have been broken by being in different blocks.

Comment: I can't see anything here that would cause such a problem. Can you post a little more complete code around that snippet? If it's truly exactly the same as the non-OO code then it shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't calling GL.GenVertexArrays to create a VAO that I was loading.   The error apparently doesn't get created when you bind the VAO, but when you first try to set a state in it.